# How to create json column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a df

```
index col1
0      a,c
1      d,f
2      o,k
```

I need a df like this

```
index col1
0     {"col1":"a,c"}
1     {"col1":"d,f"}
2     {"col1":"o,k"}
```

This needs to be applied for all columns in the df.

Tried with orient, but not as expected.

Comment: can you be more explicit on the input/output? are those strings? dictionaries? Are you missing the quotes? Ideally provide an object of both input/output

Comment: those are strings..and yes sorry im missing the quotes as well.. i tried to do replica and did mistake..

Comment: I provided several alternatives, let me know which one you want (and please update the question accordingly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all columns use double `apply`, columns name is passed by `x.name`, get dictionary:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.apply(lambda y: {x.name: y}))
```

For `json` use:

```
import json

df = df.apply(lambda x: x.apply(lambda y: json.dumps({x.name: y})))
print (df)
              col1
0  {"col1": "a,c"}
1  {"col1": "d,f"}
2  {"col1": "o,k"}
```

Alternative solution for dictionaries:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({c: [{c: x} for x in df[c]] for c in df.columns}, index=df.index)
```

Alterative2 solution for json (working well if all columns are filled by strings):

```
df = '{"' + df.columns + '": "' + df.astype(str) + '"}'
```

Comment: What is diff between normal and alternative solution..

Comment: @Kowsi - I think if large Dataframe altarnative should be faster, not tested.

Comment: the fastest is to use vectorial string concatenation as I suggested (6x faster on small df, 15x faster on 30k), but `json` will be more practical if quoting is expected (doesn't seem to be the case here though)

Comment: @mozway - I understand OP need dictionary or `json` ouput in all columns.

Comment: Yes, but you can apply the vectorial string concatenation on all columns (I updated my answer) ;)

Answer (score 1):

###### If you want strings exactly as shown, use:

```
df['col1'] = '{col1:'+df['col1']+'}'

# or 
c = 'col1'
df[c] = f'{{{c}:'+df[c]+'}'
```

output:

```
0    {col1:a,c}
1    {col1:d,f}
2    {col1:o,k}
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

or, with quotes:

```
df['col1'] = '{"col1":"'+df['col1']+'"}'

# or 
c = 'col1'
df[c] = f'{{"{c}":"'+df[c]+'"}'
```

output:

```
   index            col1
0      0  {"col1":"a,c"}
1      1  {"col1":"d,f"}
2      2  {"col1":"o,k"}
```

###### for all columns:

```
df = df.apply(lambda c: f'{{"{c.name}":"'+c.astype(str)+'"}')
```

*NB. ensure "index" is the index*

###### for dictionaries:

```
df['col1'] = [{'col1': x} for x in df['col1']]
```

output:

```
   index             col1
0      0  {'col1': 'a,c'}
1      1  {'col1': 'd,f'}
2      2  {'col1': 'o,k'}
```